# Создание графического дерева JavaScipt

Tags: javascript, поиск-библиотек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите , каким образом можно реализовать графическое отображение деревьев.
Какую графическую библиотеку лучше использовать. 
Самое главное , с чего начать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366237/7678419) комментарий, тяжело написать более подробный и структурированный обзор по библиотекам которые умею визуализировать деревья.
Лично мне, из этого списка, импонирует [d3.js](https://d3js.org/), библиотеки уже около 7-ми лет (все "детские" баги исправлены) и она имеет хорошую [производительность](http://tommykrueger.com/projects/d3tests/performance-test.php), если вы собираетесь визуализировать большие деревья.